# Resful web service standards, best practicies

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, web-standards

I am looking for best practices on restful web service standards. One of the main things I want to sort out is entity separation in url. What is the right to do, group methods in one url or separate by entityname?

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "countries/{id}")]
Country GetCountry(int id);

[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "countries/{id}", Method = "POST")]
Country CreateCountry(int id, Country country);
or 
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "resources/lists/countries/{id}")]
Country GetCountry(int id);

[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "resources/lists/countries/{id}", Method = "POST")]
Country CreateCountry(int id, Country country);
```

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rest.

Answer (score 1):

The first option is cleaner.  All URIs in a REST API should be resources so 'resources' isn't needed in the URI and I would say 'lists' isn't either since that's just a way of representing a collection of a resource.

Also, if you are going to be implementing REST services in C#, as per the example, I would highly recommend using [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).  It provides a very clean, powerful, and simple way of implementing REST services.

[Restful Web Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529260) is a great book that gives basic best practices around restful web service design and has great examples as well.  You could also check out the [Richardson Maturity Model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) which describes service restfulness in terms of levels of maturity.  For a service to be restful it would have to be at the top maturity level, but the levels give a good guide for taking steps in the right direction.